# Hard delete video from camera roll through the app in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera-roll

Is there a way to hard delete video through the app? I mean if I delete the video from app it will also be deleted from the camera roll.

Comment: i am not sure but apple wont allow to delete native content from your app. As @andrea said you can save videos, photos from, native Photo app to your appliction but you cant delete it from camera roll.

Comment: @NitinGohel: I also thought that. I just want to clarify it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends which iOS you are targeting. From iOS8 you can use the Photo Framework aka PhotoKit, with this framework is possible to delete content from camera roll.
[Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Listings/README_md.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-README_md-DontLinkElementID_4) from Apple.
 
On iOSes lower than 8 you an only fetch and save data.
This is valid if you saved the file on camera roll, as an application you can only decide to save in a particular folder of the app sandbox.

Comment: i think OP is asking for delete a native Photo app video delete from application programmatically. Your answer i don't think match with OP.

Comment: Let's the OP clarify its intent

Comment: @Andrea : I want to delete a video from camera roll through app. and your answer doesn't suggest that.

Comment: From Photokit documentation "You create and use PHAssetChangeRequest objects within a photo library change block to create, delete, or modify PHAsset objects." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/

Comment: @GobindaDas edited the answer check the sample code provided